# Re-targeting jQuery "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('.mainDiv').on('click', function(){
  $(this).animate({'width':'70%', 'height':'70%'}, 300, 'swing');
  $('p', this).stop().animate({'font-size':'70%', 'color':'#000000', 'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'swing',
    function(){
      $(?????).animate({'width':'110%', 'height':'110%', 'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'swing');
    }
  );
});
```

Question: `(?????)` how do I re-target `".mainDiv"` after targeting it's child `"p"` ?

Comment: If you're resetting the opacity back to '0' on the `p` container: the `.mainDiv` - you're most likely end up not seeing your `p` at all :)

Comment: @ Roko C. Buljan, this is a partial part of the entire code - I've got that covered. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('.mainDiv').on('click', function(){
  var $maindiv = $(this); // <= save the external "this"
  $maindiv.animate({'width':'70%', 'height':'70%'}, 300, 'swing');
  $('p', this).stop().animate({'font-size':'70%', 'color':'#000000', 'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'swing',
    function(){
      $maindiv.animate({'width':'110%', 'height':'110%', 'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'swing');
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var $this=$(this);
```

and then use `$this` when you need to refer the original element.

Answer (score 1):

I wold rather suggest using:

```
$('.mainDiv').on('click', function(){
  var that = this;
  $(this).animate({'width':'70%', 'height':'70%'}, 300, 'swing');
  $('p', this).stop().animate({'font-size':'70%', 'color':'#000000', 'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'swing',
  function(){
      $(that).animate({'width':'110%', 'height':'110%', 'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'swing');
  });
});
```

The main idea is to 'attach' the variable to some other, I personaly like it being called 'that', but there are few possible approaches.